# onclick-event on checkbox in list

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to put an onclick-event on a `<input type="checkbox">` like in the picture, which is in a `<li>` element. My js-code so far:
It doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    allFiles()
/*----------------------------------------------------------Rechteverwaltung---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------ALLE USER (Dropdown)------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json', //to parse string into JSON object
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'webAthen/api/users',
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $('.userDropdown').html("");

        for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
           $('.userDropdown').append("<option>" + data[i].userName + "</option>");
        }

    }
});

/*----------User information-LISTENER-------------------*/
    $(document).on("click", ".userDropdown > option", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'webAthen/api/getFileOfUserFile?userName=' + $('.userDropdown').val(),
                success: function (dataRights){
                    dataRights = JSON.parse(dataRights);
                    //Wenn user Rechte hat -> checked, wenn nicht, -> unchecked
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json', //to parse string into JSON object
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'webAthen/api/getAllAthenFiles',
                        success: function(dataAllFiles){
                        //alert(dataRights.length);
                            for(j=0; j < dataAllFiles.length; j++){
                                if(dataRights.length == 0){
                                    document.getElementById(j).checked = false;
                                }
                                for(i=0; i < dataRights.length; i++){
                                    if(dataAllFiles[j].id == dataRights[i].id){
                                        document.getElementById(j).checked = true;
                                        break;
                                    }else{
                                         document.getElementById(j).checked = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
     });


/*----------Set Rights-LISTENER-------------------*/
    $(document).on("click", "#fileList > li > input", function(){
            alert("Auf ... geklickt!");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'webAthen/api/getFileOfUserFile?userName=' + $('.userDropdown').val(),
                success: function (dataRights){

                }
            });
     });


/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------ALLE FILES (LIST)------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function allFiles(){

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json', //to parse string into JSON object
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'webAthen/api/getAllAthenFiles',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                checkbox.id = data[i].id;
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.value=data[i];

                $('#fileList').append("<li>");
                $('#fileList').append(checkbox);
                $('#fileList').append(" ");
                $('#fileList').append(data[i].name);
                $('#fileList').append("</li>");
            }
        }
    });
}

/*--------------multiselect----------*/
/*
$(function () {
            $('#fileDropdown').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });

});
*/

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------ALLE Gruppen (Dropdown)---------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json', //to parse string into JSON object
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'webAthen/api/groups',
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $('.groupDropdown').html("");

        for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
           $('.groupDropdown').append("<option>" + data[i].name + "</option>");
        }

    }
});

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------ALLE Sammlung (Dropdown)-----------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json', //to parse string into JSON object
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'webAthen/api/collections',
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $('.collectionsDropdown').html("");

        for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
           $('.collectionsDropdown').append("<option>" + data[i].name + "</option>");
        }

    }
});
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------SET RIGHTS USER/FILE -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
// USER FILE ZUORDNEN
 $('#zuordnen').click(function() {
    $.ajax({

        url: 'webAthen/api/addUserToFile?userName=' + $('.userDropdown').val() + "&fileName=" +$('.fileDropdown').val(),
        type: 'GET',
    });
});

// USER FILE ENTFEFRNEN
 $('#entfernen').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webAthen/api/deleteUserFromUserFile?userName=' + $('.userDropdown').val() +  "&fileName=" +$('.fileDropdown').val(),
            type: 'GET',
        });
  });
*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------INFO FILES---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
$('#info').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'webAthen/api/getUserOfUserFile?fileName='+$('.file').val(),
            success: function (data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                 $('#user').html("User mit Rechten an dieser Datei: ");

                for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                   $('#user').append(data[i].userName + ", ");
                }
            }
        });
});
*/

});
```

```css
   * {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            html, body {
              background: #f1f1f1;
              /*line-height: 18px;*/
              height: 100%;
              font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
            }

            a {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: #fff;
            }

            #container{
             height: 100%;
            }

            /*------------------------------------------Header------------------------------------*/

                #navibar ul {
                  list-style: none;
                  margin: 0;
                  padding: 0;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  background-color: #23282d;
                  border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
                }

                #navibar li {
                  float: left;
                }

                #navibar li a {
                  display: block;
                  color: white;
                  text-align: center;
                  padding: 14px 16px;
                  text-decoration: none;
                }

                /*li a:hover:not(.active) {
                  background-color: #111;
                }*/

                #navibar .active {
                  background-color: #4CAF50;
                }

                #navibar ul ul{
                  float: none;
                  position: absolute;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  /*display: none;*/
                  visibility: hidden;
                  max-width: 130px;
                  text-align: left;
                  right: 0px;
                }

                #navibar ul li a:hover{
                  background-color: #00b9eb;
                }

             /*.verticalMenu .menu .inner a:hover{
               color: #00b9eb;
             }*/

                #navibar ul li:hover > ul{
                  color: black;
                  display: block;
                  position: absolute;
                  opacitiy: 1;
                  visibility: visible;
                  transition-delay: 0.3s;
                  z-index: 999;
                }

            /*-------------------------------------------Linke-Sidebar--------------------------*/

            .btn-menu {
              height: 100%;
              display: block;
              background: #23282d;
            }

            .btn-menu .icon {
              float: right;
            }

            .verticalMenu {
              width: 280px;
              min-width: 230px;
              height: 94.35%;
              display: inline-block;
              /*line-height: 18px;*/
              background: #23282d;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }

            .verticalMenu ul{
              list-style: none;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu li a{
              color: #fff;
              display: block;
              padding: 15px 20px;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu .outer a:hover{
              background-color: #00b9eb;
              color: #fff;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu .inner a:hover{
              color: #00b9eb;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu .icon{
              font-size: 12px;
              line-height: 18px;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu .icon.left{
              float: left;
              margin-right: 10px;
              padding-top: 3px;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu .icon.right{
              float: right;
              margin-left: 10px;
              padding-top: 5px;
            }

            .inner{
                /*display:none;*/
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu ul li a {
              background: #32373c;
              color: #e9e9e9;
            }

            .verticalMenu .menu .active > a{
              background: #1a95d5;
              color: #fff;
            }

      /*--------------------------------------------------Formular--------------------------------*/
      #formular{
       position: absolute;
       top: 100px;
       left: 320px;
       display: flex;  /*float: left scheint nicht zu funktionieren*/
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      #formular > div {
          flex: 1;
          margin-left: 20px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          display: inline-block;
      }

      #formular button{
       border: none;
       color: white;
       padding: 15px 32px;
       text-align: center;
       text-decoration: none;
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 16px;
       margin-top: 10px;
       background-color: #4CAF50;
       cursor:pointer;
      }

      .design {
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #D0D0D0;
                overflow:auto;
             }

             .innerDiv {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                height: 400px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
             }

            .userDropdown{
               height: 300px;
               width: 300px;
               max-width: 300px;
            }

            ul {
              list-style-type: none;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.1.0-web/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleRechteverwaltungDatei.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="navibar">
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html"><li style="color: #ffffff ; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><img src = "Bilder/acropolisW.svg" height="40"/>  webATHEN</li></a>
            <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href=>User <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Einstellungen.html">Einstellungen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Login.html">Ausloggen</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="verticalMenu">
        <!--<a href="" class="btn-menu">Menu<i class="icon fa fa-bars"></i></a>-->
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="outer"><a href="index.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard </a></li>
            <li class="outer"><a href="#"><i class="icon left fa fa-copy"></i> Dokumentverwaltung <i class="icon right fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <ul>
                <li class="inner"><a href="DokumentverwaltungDatei.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-file"></i> Datei </a></li>
                <li class="inner"><a href="DokumentverwaltungSammlung.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-folder"></i> Sammlung </a></li>
            </ul>
            <li class="outer"><a href="#"><i class="icon left fa fa-key"></i>Rechteverwaltung <i class="icon right fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <ul>
                <li class="inner"><a href="RechteverwaltungDatei.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-file"></i> Datei</a></li>
                <li class="inner"><a href="RechteverwaltungGruppe.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-users"></i> Gruppe</a></li>
                <li class="inner"><a href="RechteverwaltungSammlung.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-folder-open"></i> Sammlung</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li class="outer"><a href="#"><i class="icon left fa fa-user"></i>Userverwaltung <i class="icon right fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <ul>
                <li class="inner"><a href="UserverwaltungUser.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-user"></i> User</a></li>
                <li class="inner"><a href="UserverwaltungGruppe.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-users"></i> Gruppe</a></li>
                <li class="inner"><a href="UserverwaltungUserGruppe.html"><i class="icon left fa fa-retweet"></i> User <i class="icon left fa fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> Gruppe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="formular">


            <div class="design">
                <h4>User:</h4> <br>
                <select class="userDropdown" size="20"></select>


            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="design">
                <h4>Files:</h4> <br>
                <div class="innerDiv">
                    <ul id="fileList"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="design">

                <h4>Userrechte einer Datei zuordnen</h4> <br>
                <label>User ausw&auml;hlen:</label>
                <select class="userDropdown"></select>
                <label>Datei ausw&auml;hlen:</label>
                <select class="fileDropdown"></select>
                <br>
                <button id="zuordnen" type="button">Rechte zuordnen</button>

           </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        <!--
          <div class = "design">

                <h4>Userrechte zu einer Datei entfernen</h4> <br>
                <label>User ausw&auml;hlen:</label>
                <select class="userDropdown"></select>
                <label>Datei ausw&auml;hlen:</label>
                <select class="fileDropdown"></select>
                <br>
                <button id="entfernen" type="button">Rechte entfernen</button>

          </div>
            <br><br>
          <div class="design">

                <h4>DateiInformationen</h4> <br>
                <label>Datei ausw&auml;hlen:</label>
                <select class="file"></select>
                <br>
                <p id="user">User mit Rechten an dieser Datei: </p>
                <button id="info" type="button">Info</button>
          </div>-->




    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/rechteverwaltungDatei.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add your html code here

Comment: Problem ist, I'm working with spark, so the checkboxes are created dynamically.

Comment: If that's what you want to do, go right ahead! Otherwise show us your code, explain what help you need, explain what you want to happen and where your current code is failing (and in what way it's failing).

Comment: @Johnny view page source, copy, paste formatted HTML here so people have the information required to help you.

Comment: Yes, now I did so, just don't want to inundate you with needless information. Just ment it in a good way :-) If you need more information, just let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $('#fileList').append("<li>");
> $('#fileList').append(checkbox);
> $('#fileList').append(" ");
> $('#fileList').append(data[i].name);
> $('#fileList').append("</li>");
> ```

The append method appends **DOM Nodes**, not fragments of HTML.

While you can type HTML there, it will be translated into DOM nodes.

Consequently, you are appending an **empty** `li` to the `ul`, then the checkbox **to the `ul`**, and so on.

Since the checkbox ends up being a child of the `ul` and not the `li`, your selector doesn't match, so the delegated event does not fire.

You need to think in terms of the DOM tree you are building and not in terms of HTML strings.

```
const $li = $("<li>");
$li.append(checkbox);
$li.append(" " + data[i].name);
$('#fileList').append($li);
```

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware of that! Tahnks a lot :-)